# Jenkins Nexus Upload different Repositories with Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, upload, nexus

within Jenkins I use the Plugin for Nexus-Artifact Uploader to load our maven deployed results into nexus.

Not unusual we have different Repositories (Snapshot and Release) in Nexus.

What I like is to determine in Jenkins in which Repository the deployed artefact should be uploaded. 
In Jenkins I can configure Parameter for that, but the plugin does not support any of these parameter.

Is the most common way to implement this within the pom.xml or has anybody solved this in the way I try to ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Nexus-Artifact-Uploader](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Nexus+Artifact+Uploader) plugin accepts input parameters and environment variables as inputs.

You can create a parameter for ex: RepoType and you can pass value as $RepoType to the repository input field.